# keeping current version while installing old version of python

Tags: python, installation, version

**CONTEXT**

I have **python 3.7.1** on my system (**macOS** Mojave 10.14.1) but need **python 3.6** for a specific package.  I want to install python 3.6 but only for use in a virtual environment while keeping 3.7 as my "default" version (i.e. the one called when typing `python3`).

**MAIN QUESTION**

*I want to be sure that installing v3.6 will not remove v3.7 from my system.*

I presume the installation will change the symbolic link.

*Is it safe to **manually** change the symbolic link back to v3.7?*

I know that `brew unlink` takes care of packages installed with Homebrew. However,while my current version of python was installed with **homebrew**, it doesn't seem possible to install specific older versions with it, so I will have to install with the macOS installer from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-367/).  I am not sure what will happen to the symlinks.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend docker for this problem.  You will never leak out of virtual environments or break system packages with docker.  Your dockerfile will explicitly define deps , not just python 3.6 exactly an image for which you can get from upstream, but also any other system deps.  Then you can turn around and run the image anywhere you like once you build it.  I have been developing in docker pretty much exclusively on my mac and love what it does for portability and replicability, not to mention being a great way to keep from having to handle package management in every execution environment.

https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/docker-for-mac/install/

Comment: hmmm... not sure this was the answer I was hoping for.  I am still very much a novice, and there always seem to be one more useful tool to get familiar with, which is fine, but this keeps delaying whatever it is that I am trying to do in the first place.  I will consider your suggestion, but for sake of knowledge, I would still like to know if the first statement in italics is correct, and know what others have to say about the second statement in italics.

Comment: I hear that.  Sometimes the tooling becomes more problematic than the problem it looks to address!  I too prefer to avoid all but the minimal toolset, and for me docker is #1 in that toolset, but of course, that's a decision everyone needs to make.   I had been using system python at my last job, but eventually it just stopped working ( pip broke spectacularly) and that's what got me started using docker for python development, but I was always happy I did.  Good luck!